# Join vs COGROUP in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Are there any advantages (wrt performance / no of map reduces ) when i  use COGROUP instead of JOIN in pig ?

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module6.html talks about the difference in the type of output they produce. But, ignoring the "output schema", are there any significant difference in performance ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no major performance differences. The reason I say this is they both end up being a single MapReduce job that send the same data forward to the reducers. Both need to send all of the records forward with the key being the foreign key. If at all, the `COGROUP` might be a bit faster because it does not do the cartesian product across the hits and keeps them in separate bags.

If one of your data sets is small, you can use a join option called ["replicated join"](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/perf.html#replicated-joins). This will distribute the second data set across all map tasks and load it into main memory. This way, it can do the entire join in the mapper and not need a reducer. In my experience, this is very worth it because the bottleneck in joins and cogroups is the shuffling of the entire data set to the reducer. You can't do this with `COGROUP`, to my knowledge.

Comment: Internally, join and cogroup are the same thing in Pig (and there is no cartesian join going on in joins, not sure what you mean there). Only the format of the end result changes depending on which keyword you used. Try "describe" on the result of a join -- you'll see the COGROUP operator in the explain plan.

Comment: What I mean by cartesian product, is that if there are multiple matches on the foreign key, you will get more records. For example, if there are 3x "abcde" in the one data set, and then 4x "abcde" in the second data set, it outputs 12x records because it matches each one up. Meanwhile, in COGROUP, it keeps the relations separate.